# Asp .net Timer Would not start

Tags: asp.net, timer

I am using timer to show working hours, which is shown on Master page.

And there is one more timer on Content page of that Master page.

now Problem is that the timer on Master Page works fine, but timer on content page don't even start.

Timer on Master page :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage1" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer_Workhrs" runat="server" OnTick="Timer_Workhrs_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
```

and the Timer_Workhrs_Tick event :

```
protected void Timer_Workhrs_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btn_Logouttime.Enabled == true)
    {
        calWorkingHrs();
    }
    else
    {
        clsLog_Tb objlog = new clsLog_Tb();
        objlog.User_Id = Session["UserName"].ToString();
        objlog.Date = DateTime.Now;
        DataSet dslg = clsUserLogic.GetLogStatus(objlog);
        if (dslg.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            lblMessage1.Text = "Working Hours:" + dslg.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Working_Hrs"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Timer on Content Page :

```
  <asp:Label ID="lbl_Lbrkresp" runat="server" Visible ="false"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Timer ID="timer_check" runat="server" Interval="1000" Enabled="false"  OnTick="timer_check_Tick">
```

Code Behind For timer_check_Tick event :

```
 protected void timer_check_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] items = lbl_LHr.Text.Split(':');
    int hours = int.Parse(items[0]);
    int mins = int.Parse(items[1]);
    int secs = int.Parse(items[2]);
    secs++;
    if (secs == 60)
    {
        mins++;
        secs = 0;
        if (mins == 60)
        {
            hours++;
            mins = 0;
            if (hours == 24) hours = 0;
        }
    }
    lbl_LHr.Text = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", hours, mins, secs);
}
```

and both timer are

```
Enabled = true;
```

Please Suggest some solution.

Comment: You have set Enabled="false" in content page.

Comment: @MairajAhmad that is design part i have Enabled it through code and have specified at the end of question